# Setting Caliburn.Micro ControlContent from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm new to Caliburn.Micro *(and MVVM for that matter)* and I'm trying to Activate a screen with my conductor located in `ShellViewModel` from a button within a sub-viewmodel (one called by the conductor). All the tutorials I've seen have buttons in the actual shell that toggle between so I'm a little lost.

All the ViewModels share the namespace `SafetyTraining.ViewModels`

The `ShellViewModel` *(first time ever using a shell so I might be using it in the wrong manner)*

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive, IHaveDisplayName
{        
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        ShowMainView();
    }

    public void ShowMainView()
    {
        ActivateItem(new MainViewModel());
    }
}
```

`ShellView` XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="SafetyTraining.Views.ShellView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DockPanel>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</DockPanel>
```

`MainViewModel` - the main screen (does correctly display).

```
public class MainViewModel : Screen
{
    public void ShowLoginPrompt()
    {
        LoginPromptViewModel lg = new LoginPromptViewModel();//This does happen
    }
}
```

`MainView` XAML

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [ShowLoginPrompt]">Login</Button>
```

`LoginPromptViewModel`

```
public class LoginPromptViewModel : Screen
{
    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");//This is for testing - currently doesn't display
    }
}
```

EDIT Working Code:

Modified Sniffer's code a bit to properly fit my structure. Thanks :)

```
var parentConductor = (Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive)(this.Parent);
        parentConductor.ActivateItem(new LoginPromptViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, but you are missing one thing though:

```
public void ShowLoginPrompt()
{
    LoginPromptViewModel lg = new LoginPromptViewModel();//This does happen
}
```

You are creating an instance of `LoginPromptViewModel`, but you are not telling the conductor to activate this instance, so it's `OnActivate()` method is never called.

Now before I give you a solution I should suggest a couple of things:

1. If you are using the `MainViewModel` to navigate between different view-models then it would be appropriate to make `MainViewModel` a conductor itself.
2. If you aren't using it like that, then perhaps you should put the button that navigates to the `LoginPromptViewModel` in the `ShellView` itself.

Now back to your problem, since your `MainViewModel` extends `Screen` then it has a `Parent` property which refers to the Conductor, so you can do it like this:

```
public void ShowLoginPrompt()
{
    LoginPromptViewModel lg = new LoginPromptViewModel();//This does happen
    var parentConductor = (Conductor)(lg.Parent);
    parentConductor.Activate(lg);
}
```

Comment: Is it customized differences or just version differences (I'm using 1.5.2) that you do it through Conductor no param (not valid for me) and Active instead of ActivateItem? Just wondering

Comment: @PRX Sorry, I don't fully understand what you are asking ?